# Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, embed

I am trying to hide the imageButton and embed based on the data coming dfrom Database for that using the following code:

```
<embed src='<%# Eval("FilePath") %>
 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
 allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" 
 width="150" height="150" runat="server" 
 Visible='<%= Eval("UploadType") == "V") %>'></embed>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnHolder" runat="server" Width="130" 
 Height="130" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("FilePath") %>' 
 Visible='<%= Eval("UploadType") != "V") %>' />
```

But when i run the above code it gives Error

> Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= Eval("UploadType") == "V") %>' for the 'Visible' property.

Can any one suggest how can i resolve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnHolder" runat="server" Width="130" 
 Visible='<%# IsVisible(Eval("UploadType"))%>'  />


 public bool IsVisible(object value)
 {
    if (value == "V")
       {
          return true;
       }
        return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a syntax error / typo. There's an extra **)** at the end of your expression -- after the **"V"**.  Same problem in the 2nd tag as well.